# Why a unlocking a locked out local account on a Windows Server immediately gets locked out again?

Tags: remote-desktop, user-accounts, windows-server, windows-server-2022

There's a Windows Server 2022 with two administrator local users. This is not Active Directory topic. One of the admins got locked out. I go ahead and uncheck the locked out status in the Local `Computer Management`'s `Local Users and Groups`, and `Apply` it. It seems to be Applied when I look back immediately.

[image: Local Computer Management Local User unlock]

However if I do anything else and I check it again, or that local admin user tries to log in via RDP (both of us access the box via RDP) the locked out checkbox gets check again.

[image: Local User login attempt via RDP]

How the hell on Earth can I get that checkbox stay unchecked and let the other admin login? I'm pulling my hair out.

---

I'm trying now a shell command:
`net user "theusername" /active:yes`
We'll see if that helps (I think it won't)

---

For the command above: the active status is not the same as locked out or not. To show more details to questions. The accounts:

[image]

When I successfully login or do something:

[image]

When things fail:

[image]

[image]

And I'm sure that this wasn't a login attempt by him. Rather it's some process? It is even spurious if something is compromised, however I don't see anything with Process Explorer, and the box is up to date. As you can see bots are constantly trying to get in but those are standard names they try.

Comment: What other events are recorded connected to the user?

Comment: @Ramhound It's hard to tell because he is the original admin account so every other normal event is logged related to his account. So when I try to filter I still get back way too many normal events to sort out the interesting ones. The user legitimately tried to login possibly with wrong password, so it's correct that he is logged out.

Comment: Also his name is not as simple as "chuck" so the bots which are constantly hammering the RDP port cannot accidentally guess his name (supposedly).

Comment: "he is the original admin account so every other normal event is logged related to his account." - What do you mean the original administrator account.  The only "original" account is the disabled built-in **Administrator** account.  Any additional user accounts, which are part of the Administrator user group, would be additional accounts. I have never seen events, logged as a user, like the way you describe.

Comment: @Ramhound He was the very first user created.

Comment: Still doesn’t make sense that events are tied to his user account.

Comment: @Ramhound I'll try to include a screenshot when I access the box while traveling. I appreciate you taking time and dealing with this.

Comment: @Ramhound I added log screenshots

Answer (score -1):

I found this Thread that shows a goup policy that you can disable... worked for me and I can now log into my admin account via RDP.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb5020282-account-lockout-available-for-built-in-local-administrators-bce45c4d-f28d-43ad-b6fe-70156cb2dc00